# Computing Smith Normal Form of $\left(\begin{smallmatrix} 1 & c_{12} & c_{13} \\ 0 & 1 & c_{23} \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ \end{smallmatrix}\right)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, math-software

I think this is a simple question, I am looking for a program which computes the [Smith normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form) or [rational canonical form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_canonical_form) of a matrix. Not something fancy, I want just to compute the Smith normal form of the following matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & c_{12} & c_{13} \\
0 &   1    & c_{23} \\
0 &   0    &   1    \\
\end{pmatrix},
$$
where the entries are from an arbitrary field. Can you help me please?

Comment: Smith normal form is for matrices over a PID, not over a field.

Comment: Yes, I mean that I want the smith normal form of the matrix $xI-A$ over $\mathbb{F}[x]$

Comment: Never tried it, but I suppose it should work over fields known to PARI.

Comment: I didn't try yet but I really need to calculate it unfortunately. Thank you for your interest though!

Comment: In this context, it's easy to compute by hand: they're the similarity invariants of $A$. One finds $\;1,1, (x-1)^3$.

Comment: @Bernard thank you for your help Bernard, I do really appreciate that. You mean that $1, 1, (x-1)^3$ are the invariant factors of the matrix $A$? Which are lying in the main diagonal of the Smith Normal Form?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42619/discussion-between-bernard-and-mayer-vietoris).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PARI GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/) has such a function. From its documentation:

> matsnf(X,{flag = 0})
>
> If X is a (singular or non-singular) matrix outputs the vector of elementary divisors of X, i.e. the diagonal of the Smith normal form of X, normalized so that d_n | d_{n-1} | ... | d_1.
>
> The binary digits of flag mean:
>
> 1 (complete output): if set, outputs [U,V,D], where U and V are two unimodular matrices such that UXV is the diagonal matrix D. Otherwise output only the diagonal of D. If X is not a square matrix, then D will be a square diagonal matrix padded with zeros on the left or the top.
>
> 2 (generic input): if set, allows polynomial entries, in which case the input matrix must be square. Otherwise, assume that X has integer coefficients with arbitrary shape.
>
> 4 (cleanup): if set, cleans up the output. This means that elementary divisors equal to 1 will be deleted, i.e. outputs a shortened vector D' instead of D. If complete output was required, returns [U',V',D'] so that U'XV' = D' holds. If this flag is set, X is allowed to be of the form `vector of elementary divisors' or [U,V,D] as would normally be output with the cleanup flag unset.
>
> The library syntax is GEN matsnf0(GEN X, long flag).